# How to get Url.Action in ASP.NET Core 2 from Startup?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Is it possible to get a URL with a kind of Url.Action from the public void Configure method of the Startup class in a ASP.net Core 2 MVC application?

If so, how?

Here the code:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });

    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        await next();
        if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404)
        {
            context.Request.Path = "/Home"; // <==== Url.Action("", "")...
            await next();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Could you use DI to inject IUrlHelper?
app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IUrlHelper>().Action("", "");

Comment: Nop, didn't work :(

Comment: Side note, calling next at the end of the pipeline is somewhat futile, especially calling it again. MVC is before you, you can't call next and expect it to pick up the request. There's a status code middleware that does something like this but you place it before Mvc.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but the answer is to use the underlying utility behind UrlHelper: [LinkGenerator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.routing.linkgenerator?view=aspnetcore-2.2):

```
var generator = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<LinkGenerator>();
var controllerName = nameof(HomeController).Replace("Controller", "");
var url = generator.GetPathByAction(nameof(HomeController.Index), controllerName)
```

Note in the sample code above I discovered that you had to trim the Controller bit off the controller class name yourself, or the result would be null.